# PHP preg_replace number to two parts

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to split number with length 5 (example "11111") into two parts with space like "111 11".

What am I missing in my code?

```
 $zip = "11111";
 $res = preg_replace('/^\d{3}[ ]?\d{2}/', '$0 $2', $zip);
 echo $zip; // returns 11111
 echo $res; // returns 11111
```

Thank you very much

---

Thanks to all, I missed simple brackets ()
I need to use this to little bit difficult methods :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[John Conde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250259/john-conde)’s answer is great, but since your question is:

> What am I missing in my code?

my answer is that you have to capture the groups with parentheses:

```
$zip = "11111";
$res = preg_replace('/^(\d{3})[ ]?(\d{2})/', '$1 $2', $zip);
echo $zip;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a regex for this? If it is always a five digit number it's easy to break it apart and reconstruct it as necessary..

```
echo sprintf("%s %s", substr($zip, 0, 3), substr($zip, -2));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H0k9rv)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regex for something so simple?

```
$zip = '11111';
$first_part = substr($zip, 0, 3);
$last_part = substr($zip, 3);
```

As for your regex, you're not using capture groups (`(...)`), so $0/$2 will never get defined.

Comment: `$last_part = substr($zip, -2);` would be better because it’s obvious from the regex used by the author that there may or may not be a space between the first three digits and the last two digits of `$zip`.